# Analysis I, Terence Tao Exercise 3.1.3

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove the remaining claims in Lemma 3.1.13. That is,
>
> i.) $A\cup B = B\cup A$
>
> ii.) $A\cup A = A\cup \emptyset = \emptyset\cup A = A$

Proof i.) Let $x\in A\cup B \iff (x\in A) \cup (x\in B) \iff (x\in B)\cup(x\in A) \iff x\in B\cup A$ (Should note I used commutative law of disjunction)

I really can't remember how to do ii.) any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $A\subseteq A\cup S$ for any set $S$, since if $a\in A$ then it is true that $a$ is either in $A$ or in $S$.

Thus, to prove (ii), it remains to show that in each case $A\cup S\subseteq A$ (since if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $A=B$).

Now if $b\in A\cup A$, then by definition of the union either $b\in A$ or $b\in A$, which means that $b\in A$ and thus $A\cup A\subseteq A$. Similarly if $b\in A\cup\varnothing$ then either $b\in A$ or $b\in \varnothing$, but the latter cannot occur (by definition of $\varnothing$) and thus $b\in A$. Thus $A\cup \varnothing\subseteq A$ and similarly for $\varnothing\cup A$.